# Next js and react js for web development

Tags: javascript, npm, next.js

When  I run my next js project it gives me this feedback:

```
next\swc-win32-x64-msvc\next-swc.win32-x64-msvc.node is not a valid Win32 application.
\\?\C:\Users\ABDUL-MOOMIN IS-HAQ\Desktop\Desktop\lms_app\node_modules\@next\swc-win32-x64-msvc\next-swc.win32-x64-msvc.node
 ⨯ Failed to load SWC binary for win32/x64, see more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.